# How can I change Git remote repository?

Tags: python, docker, flask, heroku

Consider (in [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell)):

```
cd C:\.dev\despesas-python
heroku create app-despesas-pessoais-python
```

Output:

```
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 8.0.5.
Creating ⬢ app-despesas-pessoais-python... done
https://app-despesas-pessoais-python.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/app-despesas-pessoais-python.git
```

And:

```
git push heroku main
```

Output:

```
remote: !       No such app as radiant-gorge-67370.
fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/radiant-gorge-67370.git/' not found
```

And:

```
git push heroku main app-despesas-pessoais-python
```

Output:

```
error: src refspec app-despesas-pessoais-python does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/radiant-gorge-67370.git'
```

And:

```
git push heroku app-despesas-pessoais-python
```

Output:

```
error: src refspec app-despesas-pessoais-python does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/radiant-gorge-67370.git'
```

I want to deploy to https://git.heroku.com/app-despesas-pessoais-python.git, but an error gives me out.
It failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/radiant-gorge-67370.git'.
Is there a way to connect to the new Heroku repository address?

Answer (score 0):

Step 3 - Add new a [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku) remote:
`git remote set-url heroku https://git.heroku.com/app-despesas-pessoais-python.git`

Step 4 - Add changes to the repository:
`git add .`

Step 5 - Commit changes to the repository:
`git commit -m [file]`

step 6 - Push to the repository:
`git push heroku main`